# SSRS Collapsed (hidden) rows still show up when exporting

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-grouping

I am writing a SSRS 2005 report in BIDS 2008 which has recursive grouping and a visibility toggle. Initial toggle state is false, so all detail rows are hidden. When I view the report in the preview window, it shows up correctly, similar to below.

```
+Group 1
+Group 2
+Group 3
```

However, when I switch to print layout or export the report, the first group will always show up as expanded like below.

```
Group 1
    Detail 1
    Detail 2
Group 2
Group 3
```

So far I've tried using a different set of data in case it was caching the results and their expand/collapse status. I've also tried deleting and then recreating the group. I've even tried creating an entirely new report project and recreating everything. All to no avail.

Has anyone encountered this before and been able to fix it?

EDIT:

I set this report aside for a few days and came back to it this morning. I started a new report and slowly rebuilt it, changing a few values each time and checking to see if the issue popped up. What I found was that the first group does not get expanded when exporting until you add a header/footer to the report. As soon as you do, the export starts to expand the group.

Further, the header/footer only causes the issue when one of them has an expression, parameter, or built-in field (execution time, for example). If the header and footer are made up of only static values (i.e. "Report Title"), then everything works fine.

For example, I added a header with a single textbox. In the textbox, I typed in "Report Name". When I tested it, the issue did not occur and the groups remained collapsed. I then went back and changed the value of the textbox to '="Report Name"'. This time the issue did occur and the first group expanded automatically.

So, my question is now why does using dynamic data in the header/footer cause the print layout view/export to completely expand the first group and all of its sub-groups?

Comment: You could use the Row visibility of those rows and set it to hidden when exporting and true when rendering on screen.

Comment: That would just flip my problem around, though. I want the export to match what is rendered on screen. Setting the row visibility manually when exporting will just make the detail rows hidden all the time instead of showing all the time.